# Error: Dynamic Linking Error: Win32 error 193 while binding to Eztwain3.dll library using nodejs ffi

Tags: node.js, dll, ffi, node-ffi

I successfully bound my nodejs to the 'TSCLIB.dll' using the ffi, but when I want to bind it to 'Eztwain3.dll', I always have "Error: Dynamic Linking Error: Win32 error 193".

```
C:\Users\dev\Desktop\nodeApp>node scan.js
C:\Users\dev\Desktop\nodeApp\node_modules\ffi\lib\dynamic_library.js:74
    throw new Error('Dynamic Linking Error: ' + err)
    ^

Error: Dynamic Linking Error: Win32 error 193
    at new DynamicLibrary (C:\Users\dev\Desktop\nodeApp\node_modules\ffi\lib\dynamic_library.js:74:11)
    at Object.Library (C:\Users\dev\Desktop\nodeApp\node_modules\ffi\lib\library.js:45:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dev\Desktop\nodeApp\scan.js:17:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
```

The execution shown above appear when I'm trying to run this script.

```
const ffi = require('ffi');
const ref = require('ref');

    const platform = process.platform;
    var lib = null;

    if (platform === 'win32') {
        lib = 'Eztwain3.dll';
    } else {
        throw new Error('unsupported plateform for lib')
    }

    var instance = ffi.Library(lib, {

    });
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwFm6.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ozt4P.jpg

I tried to execute the same script with 'TSCLIB.dll' and it run without exeption.
So, how can I call the 'Eztwain3.dll' library with node ffi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolve my problem by changing the nodejs from 64bit to 32bit because my dll is 32 bit

Comment: How do you change your nodejs from 64bit to 32bit? Re-install?

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same issue.
Use sigcheck to find that the dll is 32bit, while node is 64bit version.
There're two solutions:

1. Replace 32bit dll with 64bit one, if you can get one.
2. Replace node 64bit with 32bit one.